# Posting on on a users wall on behalf of the user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out if the following is possible with the Graph API:

- Post a message on the wall of a user (who has permissions publish_stream and offline_access set) on behalf of that user, so the poster doesn't depend on the current session.

This seemed to be possible with the old rest api ([stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish)). This function has some known bugs though and seems te be deprecated.

With the new api it's possible to publish on a users wall but it doesn't take the poster as an argument (as did stream.publish). See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing).

Is this because Facebook doesn't allow such third party publishing anymore, or am I missing something here?
Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

from here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api

> If you have an authenticated user with
>   the publish_stream permission, and
>   want to publish a new story to their
>   feed:

```
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response);
  }
});
```

it is the javascript version but i am pretty sure there is an equivalent one for php

Comment: This works if the user is currently logged in ('me/feed'), but in my case the user is offline and I want to post on behalf of that user. Replacing the /me with an id doesn't work because there is no session for that user.

Comment: then you probably require the offline_access permission.

Comment: I think it has to be done by using the `accessToken` because the user id doesn't know whether the app has the permission. Unfortunately I don't know how to pass the users unique `accessToken`. Probably as param in the `.api` function as suggested here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12197818/1303917](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12197818/1303917)
I didn't test it yet.
  
**Update**: I just saw the age of this post. But maybe it's helpful anyway.