# set user (access token) within FB.init

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token, facebook-javascript-sdk

i want to publish story to user timeline even when they were not login with facebook. Actually I stored user access token in the database, if the user login in with email, i'll retrieve the access token for her. It works well in php (e.g get friends list after setAccessToken(token_from_database), but when i post the story, it always post to current fb login account's timeline.

I think the problem is caused by fb.init:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXX', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };
```

and later:

```
FB.api('/me/...
```

take login account as "me", not the one I set in php through setAcccessToken. 
How could i post to that account (specify with token_from_database) 's timeline? any idea?

Answer (score 24):

Try passing the access token you want to use as part of the `params` object you give to `FB.api` – it should work the same way as it does when accessing the API server-side.

```
FB.api(
  '/me/feed',
  'post',
  {
    access_token : 'access_token_for_some_user_fetched_from_your_database',
    additional_parameter_foo : 'bar'
  }
);
```

Comment: for all who are coming here for this, passing access_token in parameters works! thanks Mario and CBroe!

Comment: Thank you so much!! it seems like FB dudes are not interested in publishing a simple and clear documentation on Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have more knowledge reagrding the PHP SDK, but in PHP you could just replace the "me" with the user id and I suppose it will work for you as well:

```
FB.api('/'+fbuserid+'/...');
```

But you should be aware that the access token of the users change, after changing passwords and logging in and out from Facebook.

Comment: Replacing `/me` with `/userid` will only change the “receiver” of that API call, but it will not change the access token used.

Comment: But that's what he wants to do or not? He wants to post to a certain timeline given by user id but posted by the user whose access token he has - thats the way I understood the question. Mario wrote: "How could i post to that account (specify with token_from_database)'s timeline?" By that I understand he only wants to change the receiver... but not the one posting. Well I guess Mario will resolve this.